# Compare lines of 2 input files, and output third file with differences

Tags: python, file, function, compare, output

I have a function working that allows me to enter two files text files, compares these text files, and finally creates a third file with the differences. It works for each line within a file, and for it to work, the whole line of text must be similar in file 1 and file 2 for it to register. This is my problem, I wish to compare the lines based only on the first word behind the colon for the lines to the similar - the text after the colons doesn't need to be the same.

The structure of the files are like so;

File 1 example:

```
A:dog 
B:cat 
C:bird 
D:cow 
E:pig
```

File 2 example:

```
B:sheep
D:duck
```

I wish the ouput of the newly created file (File 3) to have the contents of:

```
A:dog
C:bird
E:pig
```

I would like the function to output the entries from file 1 that aren't in file 2 based only upon the first string (letter) before the semicolon. This currently only works if the entire line of text within File 2 is identical to File 1:

```
def comparison(F1,F2,F3):
   with open(F1, 'r') as f:
      d=set(f.readlines())
   with open(F2, 'r') as f:
      e=set(f.readlines())
   open(F3, 'a').close()
   with open(F3, 'a') as f:
      for line in list(d-e):
         f.write(line)

comparison('file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt')
```

I have mainly tried using `line.split(':')[0]` to grab the first string before the colon to compare, but haven't been successful.

Comment: OK... so you want to output a list of lines where the text before the colon is unique to one of the files?

Comment: Yes :). If the text before the colon is not in File 2, I'd like it input into file 3 from file 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick interpreter session to show a process using defaultdict. I'll leave it to you to fill in the file I/O.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> list1 = ['a: xyz', 'b:123']
>>> list2 = ['a: dupe', 'c:456']
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in list1 + list2:
...     k,v = item.split(':')
...     d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [' xyz', ' dupe'], 'c': ['456'], 'b': ['123']})
>>> ['{}:{}'.format(k,d[k][0]) for k in d if len(d[k]) == 1]
['c:456', 'b:123']
```

**Update**: an example with file i/o, by request.

```
from collection import defaultdict
list1 = open('file1.txt', 'r').readlines()
list2 = open('file2.txt', 'r').readlines()
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in list1 + list2:
    k,v = item.split(':')
    d[k].append(v)
with open('file3.txt', 'a') as output:
    output.writelines(['{}:{}\n'.format(k,d[k][0]) for k in d if len(d[k]) == 1])
```

To unpack that last line in English, it means:

- Step through the keys in d (our dict)
- Ignore items where we added more than one item for that key
  (non-unique key)
- For each item we're not ignoring (is unique), format the key and
  value back into a 'k:v' string and add a newline character
- For that collection of re-assembled strings (plus newlines), write the
  whole thing down to our file.

Comment: Woah, this is out of my league :) - is there a simpler way to do it using the code I gave in my question?

Comment: @Eric1989 Ha... this leverages some Python idioms that are a bit compact at first glance, but well worth the effort to learn. FMI: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: I'll take the time to learn this read this; but for now, is there a more 'beginner' way to achieve this using a similar structure to my code in the question? It's primarily for leaning purposes and this is too big a gap for me at the moment. :D - Thanks so much for the help btw.

Comment: The way you're doing it is not working because you want to compare two sets based on *one* characteristic of the elements, not the elements themselves being identical. I promise that a dictionary where this "matching" characteristic is used as a key is the very most efficient way to handle this case, as you only need to iterate over each collection once. If you don't use a dict, you're probably going to end up iterating over list2 by len(list1) number of times, or vice versa.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would it be possible for you to edit your answer as to work  by using two input files and outputting the results into a third? I'd be much appreciative as I'm struggling to understand yours at the moment and would like to see it work before trying to grasp it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is many ways to achieve your objective. And actually you were pretty close. The idea to use a set to handle the values is a nice way to evaluate the difference between the two lists in each file. But, you need to separate the values before the colon from the values after the colon, otherwise you will compare the whole line which would be wrong in your case. After you get the difference, you will need to retrieve - based on the difference - the whole lines from the two files to write them in a new file.

So, one idea for solution is: when you are reading one file, you save each line in a dictionary to make it retrievable in the future, and also, save the values before the colon in a set (a set for each file) to evaluate the difference of values (as you already did).

Practically it means:

```
d = {}  # Our dictionary to store the lines
a = set()  # a set for the first file
b = set()  # a set for the second file

with open('file1') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        key, value = line.split(':')  # this separate the values in each line
        d[key] = value.strip()  # add one line to the dictionary
        a.add(key)  # save just the value from the colon left
```

Then, you need to the same with the second file. Perhaps you would make it as a function to make your code rocks and more maintainable.

After this, you will have a complete dictionary. Since you don't want to write repeated values, it is ok that our code overwrite some values.

Now, you need to evaluate the difference. The way you did it is fine. But it just works if you know that the first file has more values than the second and maybe other issues too. You will need to take a look at set methods to achieve this properly (TIP: unions and intersections) but lets do in the way you did:

```
diff = a - b
```

Finally, lets write the results retrieving them from the dictionary based on our difference:

```
with open('results', 'w') as fp:
    for key in diff:  # you can use sorted(diff) instead just diff here
        fp.write("{0}:{1}\n".format(key, d[key]))
```

Of course, this way is not the more pythonic way, but it is some kind straightforward. Other answers may be simpler than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use should put the files in CSV format. So just put them in the excel and save it as CSV.

After do this.

```
f = open('file1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
animals1 = []

for row in csv_f:
    animals1.append(row[0])   #[] put number in there. 0 = first Column 
f.close()

f = open('file2.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
animals2 = []

for row in csv_f:
    animals2.append(row[0])      
f.close()


animals1 = set(animals1)
animals2 = set(animals2)

print animals1.difference(aniamls2)
```

so this code basically reads your csv file, and prints out the difference.
you could implement this and write it in to a new file.

Comment: Is there a similar way to do this with text files that you know of?

Comment: do you have to do this in text file?

Comment: It's for learning purposes so I'd ideally like to be able to do it in a text file, haha. I'm just stuck at the moment - the code I have in the question is the best I can do but it only compares the whole line of text, not the string before the colon.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Caveat, as per the comments on this answer: This method is not the best way to go about solving this problem. But it does seem to answer the question the user was posing based on his further commentary...

OP asked for a "simpler" way to do this without dictionaries.  This can be done by reading in all the lines of each file and then getting the first letter only of each line.  Then filter the data based on an array of letters in file2.  This is going to be very dependent on the specific format of the text files, and on the fact that file1 is filtered by file2 not vice versa. But, that said, the python to do this should look something like this (the line numbers are from my text editor, not part of the code):

```
1 f=open("./file1.txt","r")
2 data1=f.readlines()
3 letter1=[]
4 f.close()
5 
6 g=open("./file2.txt","r")
7 data2=g.readlines()
8 letter2=[]
9 g.close()
10 
11 #just take the first character (the 'A', 'B', etc)
12 for dat in data1:
13     letter1.append(dat[0]) 
14 for dat in data2:
15     letter2.append(dat[0])
16 
17 h=open("output.txt","w")
18 for dat in data1:
19     if dat[0] not in letter2:
20         h.write(dat)
21 
22 h.close()
```

Comment: Hello - thanks for answering. I've just tested this and it half works. The first line of File 1 (A:dog) isn't showing in the output file?

Comment: @hft Agreed that this is what the OP was asking for. It's not a good answer, however, as your workload increases dramatically if file1 and/or file2 are large. Even for learning purposes (perhaps especially for learning purposes) I would really avoid comparing collections this way. You're iterating over all items of letter2 len(data1) number of times.

Comment: @Eric1989, it seems to work fine for me. Not sure why the first line isn't showing up for you... maybe there is some other character (like a space) at  the beginning of the first line.

Comment: @dylrei, yeah, you're right. I just figured I'd give the guy what he asked for. It will work fine for his tiny example files and if he ever needs to do this for large input, he will figure out soon enough that it doesn't work well...